2D Poisson's Equation in spherical coordinates
Earth's atmosphere is a sphere over $R\le r$, and the horizontal velocity field of the atmosphere at a constant height level is the sum of the purely rotational and purely divergent horizontal velocity vectors:
$$V = V_\psi + V_\chi \\ \hat{\textbf{r}}\cdot\nabla\times V_\chi = 0 \\ \nabla \cdot V_\psi = 0$$
On the full periodic domain (ignoring data holes due to mountains and general changes in elevation) $V_\chi$ and $V_\psi$ are unique solutions and can be found by solving two separate Poisson's equations:
$$\Delta \chi = \nabla \cdot V = \delta \\ \Delta \psi = \hat{\textbf{r}}\cdot\nabla \times V = \zeta$$,
where $\delta$ is horizontal divergence, $\zeta$ is vertical vorticity due to the horizontal wind field, $\chi$ is called the $\textit{velocity potential}$ and $\psi$ is the $\textit{streamfunction}$, and $V_\chi = \nabla \chi$ and $V_\psi = \hat{\textbf{k}}\times\nabla \psi$. We'll use the following idealized 3D wind field:
$$U(r,\theta,\phi) = r\hat{\textbf{r}} + -\frac{r}{2}\cot\theta \hat{\theta} + \frac{r}{2}\phi\sin\theta \hat{\phi}$$
And the horizontal velocity field at some height level, $r=a$, is
$$U(r=a,\theta,\phi) = V(\theta,\phi) = 0\hat{\textbf{r}} + -\frac{a}{2}\cot\theta \hat{\theta} + \frac{a}{2}\phi\sin\theta \hat{\phi}$$
And for now, I'm only interested in finding $\chi$, so to lighten the workload, we'll be using this vector field to find just the horizontal divergence:
$$\delta = \frac{1}{a^2}\frac{d r^2 \cdot 0}{dr} + -\frac{a}{2a\sin\theta}\frac{d \sin\theta \cot\theta}{d\theta}+\frac{a\sin\theta}{2a\sin\theta}\frac{d \phi}{d\phi} = 1$$

After laying out the foundation for my specific problem, I can move forward to what I am getting stuck on, and that is how to find the solution to Poisson's Equation on the surface of a single spherical shell at $r=a$? I'm used to finding the solution for all $r$ by using spherical harmonics to separate the angular terms and then solving an ODE based on the radial variable, but without a radial component to our solution to separate out, I would probably use a different method, but that is the only method I'm familiar with for working on Poisson's Equation in a spherical coordinate scheme.
This is what the PDE should look like:
$$\Delta \chi(\theta,\phi) = 1 \\ \cases{\chi(\theta,0) = \chi(\theta,2\pi) \\ \chi(\theta,0)' = \chi(\theta,2\pi)'}$$
Also, not sure if this problem is determinable or if we'd end up with unspecified integration constants, but notwithstanding that, I'd still be interested to learn of the method for working this out if possible.

There are a couple of issues. Where does your $U$ come from ? It is ill defined since $\phi$ is multivalued. Secondly, to solve Poisson's equation on a sphere, the sources need to average to zero, i.e. $$\int\delta\sin\theta d\theta d\phi = 0$$ So your problem is ill posed. This follows from Gauss' law $$\int\nabla\cdot V d^2x = \oint  V\cdot dx = 0$$ More generally, I don't understand your approach, if you already have $U$ (so $V$), just solve for $\chi$ and $\psi$ directly.

@LPZ 1) U is the wind field that exists at a moment in time. 2) If you’re asking what causes the horizontal wind, it’s caused entirely by the horizontal pressure gradient force, and is influenced by other terms like Coriolis. It’s all laid out in the horizontal momentum equation $\frac{dV}{dt}$ and we tend to neglect all terms but PGF. 3) As for your second statement, I’ve not heard of that requirement before, so would this be unsolvable then? 4) I’m asking what methods are used to solve this for just a 2D shell because I simply wanted to for my own learning purposes. Is it possible or not?

@LPZ I've performed the separation of variables and obtained $$\Phi'' + m^2\Phi=0$$ and the associated Legendre Equation $$(1-x^2)y'' - 2x y' - \frac{m^2}{1-x^2}y = 0$$. For the second ODE, we have no $\lambda$ to substitute $l(l+1)$ which complicates things

@LPZ I’m going to focus on remaking problem so that it is better posed
